# DOM vs Application

Tags: angularjs, dom

Recently in a tutorial it is said that Angularjs generates an application and not a DOM.
My question is what is the difference between DOM and application?
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOM is the fundamental way that a browser presents the page content to Javascript and allows Javascript to interact with it.

Angularjs layers on top of this to provide higher level abstractions and isolate you from the DOM so you don't generally have to interact with it directly.

Asking what is DOM vs what is an application isn't really a question that makes any sense, the two are not comparable like that.  DOM is an API used by javascript to manipulate the page.  An application is a collection of code that does something useful.